# Can we get a "remind me" feature for reviews?

Tags: feature-request, review, notifications

I like participating in the review queues from time to time, and every now and then, I come across a post that I make a recommendation on, that, I would like to follow up on after a set amount of time. For example, a new user answers a rather dated existing question, which places their answer in the "Late Answers" queue. Their answer isn't that great of quality in its current state, but it *does* answer the question at hand.

In cases such as this, I typically recommend improving the answer with some detailed information (links to sources, step by step instructions, more thorough explanations, etc). This enables the author to make changes before I downvote their post, which would relay a more inviting experience, IMHO, for those less versed in the expectations of posting on Stack Exchange sites.

Unfortunately though, in order to follow up on the question, not only do I have to remember it, I have to navigate to my profile and dig through my review activity (which, if I'm reviewing heavily it *might* be a few pages back).

***Edit**: It was pointed out in the comments that we could follow posts from the review queue:*

[image: Screenshot of the follow link.]

However, it is my understanding that this will notify of changes made to a post; but, this is not what I'm looking for. I'm looking to remember to follow up, even if the author doesn't make a change.

---

Can we get a feature that would remind us to follow up on a post we reviewed? This feature could be an additional link on the post (to the right of flag?) that only displays if you're reviewing the post through the queue. It could then ask for a date (no need for time IMHO), and you then get a notification on that date through the site inbox. Additionally, if we could click that notification (like we do existing ones for comments) to navigate to the post, that would be fantastic!

Comment: Can't you follow a post from the review queue? https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJlp4.png and then https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JOw5.png

Comment: @rene you can, but following it only notifies you of changes right? If so, then what about the case where the author ignores you and makes no change?

Comment: I regularly check in on the posts I've followed, to see if further action (comment pokes, flags, etc.) need to be taken.

Comment: You want a notification if between you following the post and 6 to 8 days later no action took place? Don't you get a blue marker if something became active?

Comment: @rene precisely, that way I don't have to remember (I'm often too busy with work to keep track).

Comment: @bobble that's what I'm trying to remedy because I don't have a lot of time to do that.

Comment: it feels a bit counter intuitive to get a notification that nothing happened. If anything it should be an opt-in feature . Here on meta I follow the SEDE documentation Q/A. I don't want notifications nothing changed because that is exactly why I follow that Q/A, I don't expect that q/a to change. If something changed I want to know it, hence the notification.

Comment: @rene well having it as a separate link, accessible only from the review queue would make it *opt-in* correct? It would be a run-once type thing with a target date.

Comment: There are two userscripts which will do the primary task for which you've asked: reminder of a post at a future date: Both SOCVR's Request Generator ([GitHub](//git.io/SOCVR-CVRG-MakNewVer)) ([install](//github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/UserScripts/raw/CVRG-Mak-new-version/SECloseVoteRequestGenerator.user.js)) (for which I'm a substantial contributor; the "revisit" request types are what will do what you want, including opening the post for you in a window/tab after an arbitrary length of time), and [Stack Reminder - Remind Yourself About Posts](https://stackapps.com/q/8163/29529).